# Confusion regarding Factory Reset via TWRP

Tags: twrp, factory-reset, data-recovery, android-10, data

**Background** The OS is Android 10 that uses FBE as encryption type.

**Problem** I do not remember my PIN, that would decrypt the files in /data partition, so I cannot unlock my screen.

**Question** I can boot into recovery (TWRP). And, naturally, TWRP asks for PIN to decrypt the files.

But if I choose not to enter the PIN, and decrypt the files, and go straight to do a ***Factory Reset via TWRP,*** will I be able to access my files (images, media) in internal storage? *(/data/media/0/)*

Comment: The PIN that you forgot is one of the  essential pieces to decrypt user data (includes /data/data/ and /data/media/USER_ID). If you don't have your PIN then you can't have your data. There is no workaround. If you can remember the length of your PIN, you can try bruteforcing through recovery (don't know if keymaster would slow this down). // Factory reset would delete all of your data including /data/media/*. Even if you do a partial reset (leaving /data/media intact), nothing useful would come out. /data/media would remain encrypted anyway without your PIN.

Comment: Thank you so much for clearing this out, I didn't have much hope as it is, regarding the data in internal storage but you cleared my doubts! Thank you again! The thing is it is either a 4 or 5 digits PIN ending with 7 and I need a custom script for that, to try brute forcing. And yes, I completely agree with you, it makes total sense.